# VBA -- faster way to deal with numbers stored as text

Tags: excel, vba

I have this function which manages to remove all numbers stored as text:

```
Public Function find_numbers_formated_as_text(ByVal sh As Worksheet)
    
    Dim c As Range
    
    On Error GoTo A
    
    ''''For Each r In sh.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
    For Each c In sh.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
    ''''For Each c In sh.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    ''''For Each c In sh.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        If IsNumeric(c.Value) = True Then
            c.Value = c.Value
        End If
    Next c
    
    Exit Function
    
A:
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

But it is really slow... Does anyone have any suggestion on how to make it faster?

---

I did try some other things which is why there are some of the comments in the source code. But comments didn't work, because range was also empty in my case (even if table was full of data).

Comment: Please, explain what kind of formulas do you have in the respective list object. And how will them return a string. Or was only a matter of formatting, applied after it used to return correctly?

Comment: @FaneDuru some formulas return string and some return a number.

Comment: Examples, please...

Comment: Did you somehow solved your problem? If not, do you really need a solution? If So, is it so difficult to show us some of the formulas you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, replace this part of your code:

```
     For Each C In sh.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
    ''''For Each c In sh.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    ''''For Each c In sh.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        If IsNumeric(C.Value) = True Then
            C.Value = C.Value
        End If
    Next C
```

with this one:

```
  Dim lRng As Range, arr, i As Long, j As Long
  
  Set lRng = sh.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
  arr = lRng.Value2
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        If IsNumeric(arr(i, j)) Then arr(i, j) = CDbl(arr(i, j))
    Next j
  Next i
  With lRng
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value2 = arr
  End With
```

It places the range in an array and all process take place only in memory, the modified array content being dropped at the end of the code, at once.

The most time consuming is the iteration between each cell and writing cell bay cell...

If "General" formatting may bother your list object format, please state in which columns the conversion should be done, and I will adapt the code to format only the respective table columns.

Now I could see one of your comments saying that in the range to be processed exist (and must remain) formulas. The above code does not deal with such a situation. You should state it in your question, I think...

**Edited**:

If the formulas used to return a numeric value (not a string) and, by mistake the respective range has been formatted as Text, you can try the next way (to maintain the formulas):

```
    With sh.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Formula = .Formula
    End With
```

Comment: Could you change `.Value2` with `.Formula` ? (regarding the formula-part)

Comment: @tnavidi Not really... The formula can be evaluated inside the loop, but if it returns a string, something as "10", how to be changed only by formatting, without transforming it in value? I cannot even understand (now) what is happening in his table. If a formula should return a number, formatting the respective range as Text will only show the formula and make it unusable... Am I missing anything on the issue? I can even process each formula to eliminate some double quotes if I would know what is it about, but I cannot understand too much from the question, anymore.

Comment: @FaneDuru This code fails. Line `.NumberFormat = "General"` triggers an error `Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class`.

Comment: @FaneDuru my answer below works in my own example workbook, but I don't know what can bring up the object error. If you use formula it gets the formula text "`=SUM(...)`" rather than the evaulated sum or anything that would evaluate to "10"

Comment: @tnavidi Yes, and how (without evaluation) to know that the formula result is numeric? Without knowing what kind of formulas he uses and **how such formulas started to return a string**, I cannot say anything. I would not be very surprised if the formulas really return a string, which cannot be handled in a normal way. I asked a clarification question about the 'history' of these formulas returning a string. The single scenario would be that they used to return a numeric value, and after that somebody format the range as Text.

Comment: @71GA This cannot happen if you `Set` the range as in the above code. `.NumberFormat` is a property of a range. Anyhow, the above code is not able to handle/keep formulas...

Comment: @FaneDuru Ah. I see. One of the cells in the table's body was locked and sheet was protected.

Comment: @FaneDuru I managed to make your solution work. There is only one thing weird about it. It converted a `9,22` (stored as a text) to a `922.00` (double). Do you know why?

Comment: @71GA which is your system decimal separator?

Comment: @FaneDuru My system's decimal specifier is `.`.

Comment: @71GA It does it because of your System `ThousandsSeparator`, which is comma. What should  "I managed to make it work" mean? Did you change anything in the code? Then, at what solution are you referring to? The first one, and you abandoned the formulas problem, or the second one? 1. Should the strange conversion take place **in a column/row to be excluded**? I mean, all the cells in that column/row should be strings/Text. If so, you should tell me the respective column/row number. 2. Does this strange conversion take place in columns/rows where **not only strings have to exist**?

Comment: @71GA In fact what do you want happening in the mentioned case? To let it a string, as it is, or to convert it differently? As 9.22, for instance?

Comment: @FaneDuru To convert it as `9.22`. There is also one more problem that I discovered. If I have a cell with `NumberFormat` set to text, i.e. `@` then if the value inside is `223E-001` then this is converted to double which I don't want. I have to somehow detect `NumberFormat` and and if format is `@` conversion shouldn't happen. But is this possible with an array?

Comment: @71GA You did not answer all my clarification questions... So, I do not know what is to be done... I will also ask some more after you will clarify them. Or, if not something confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of answers to this question. This is a simple thing to try. Add this before:

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

and this after:

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

Comment: Why does this makes things faster?

Comment: Every time you change a value, all formulas are recalculated. This is normally what you would want to happen, but in a case like this, there is no reason for doing it between every operation. Once the big change is done, it's back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

It's faster to store the range as array than changing values in the sheet.

```
sh.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.formula = sh.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.formula
```

The numbers will default to numbers if they were text so you don't need to test if it's number.

(You will not lose formulas using this method.)

Comment: It's even easier: `sh.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Value = sh.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Value`

Comment: @tnavidi Interesting. But I can't afford to loose formulas.

Comment: I've edited my answer, it will keep formulas intact and convert numbers-stored-as-text to numbers

Comment: This brings up an object error.

Comment: The code i used to test was this `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Formula = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Formula` as i didn't use DataBodyRange (since I don't have your excel sheet)

Comment: This solution deletes my table...